# Stretch TextBox in StackPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml

This is the current XAML i'm using to do this... and for the life of me cannot figure out how to expand the textbox to fill the entire column. Could anyone please guide me in the correct direction?

Thank you in advance!

[image: Picture of issue]

```
<Grid>        
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="15" />
        <RowDefinition Height="15" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!--ROW 0-->
    <TextBlock Text="DOMAIN:"/>
    <!--ROW 1-->
    <Separator Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

    <!--ROW 2-->
    <TextBlock  Text="Connection credentials:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
        <Button Content="EDIT" Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}" Width="80" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="CurrentCredentialslbl" Text="Connect as:" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ROW 3-->
    <TextBlock  Text="Find accounts in domain:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBox />
        <Button Content="Browse" Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}" Width="80" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ROW 4-->
    <CheckBox  Content="Only search in this container" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I would like to point out, HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" doesn't work either... i'm sure i'm missing something small.

Comment: Try HorizontalContentAllignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Grid` with 2 columns instead of `StackPanel` should fit perfectly

```
<Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" 
            Content="Browse" 
            Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}" 
            Width="80" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This helped me, I never thought of having another grid inside of a grid.row.... thanks! :)

Comment: @TonyW, `Grid` is just another UIElement and can be used inside StackPanel, Grid, DataTemplate, etc